# NRF52 How to erase a protected firmware program (knowing the protected password)

Tags: nrf52

I'm trying to deploy a new firmware to my hardware device but I get the following error in the nrf  Connect (v3.6.1) Programmer (v1.4.8):

- 16:47:36.937
  Error when getting device info: Error: Error: Error occured when get device info. Errorcode: CouldNotCallFunction (0x9) Lowlevel error: NOT_AVAILABLE_BECAUSE_PROTECTION (ffffffa6)
- 16:47:36.937
  Could not fetch memory size of target devkit: Cannot read property 'family' of undefined

I cannot read nor erase from the device through the programmer because of this error.

I assume this is because the device is password protected. I know this password, is there a way to erase the device's current firmware?

(I'm using the NRF52-DK to connect/program with it, and the pins are accessible, which is how I'm connecting and I know the chipset is a nrf52840)
Wiring now is as followed:

[image]

So I'm currently not using the debug output to connect with the device

I've provided power to the custom device by batteries now, no change in the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by a "device password" for the nRF52840.

NOT_AVAILABLE_BECAUSE_PROTECTION occurs when the APPROTECT register has been enabled. According to the nRF52840 product spec

> Access port protection is disabled by issuing an ERASEALL command via CTRL-AP

Alternatively, if you are using pynrfjprog, the `recover()` method removes the protection.

No matter what, flash will always be erased when clearing APPROTECT (unless utilizing the [APPROTECT power glitch](https://limitedresults.com/2020/06/nrf52-debug-resurrection-approtect-bypass/), but that's another topic)

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenOCD 0.11.0 (binaries available from  https://github.com/xpack-dev-tools/openocd-xpack/releases/tag/v0.11.0-1/ )

The following commands will remove the chip protection and reprogram the chip (with the lp.hex program)

```
bin\openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/nrf52.cfg -c "telnet_port pipe;tcl_port disabled;gdb_port disabled;log_output 
reset init
nrf52_recover
flash write_image s132_nrf52_2.0.1_softdevice.hex
flash write_image lp.hex
reset
```

This works for all versions fo the chips including the later versions (build Gxx and later) which automatically re-apply chip protection on reset.

For those of you using Arduino, my [Very Low Power BLE <20uA](https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/BLE/LowPower_2022/index.html) project automates this process in the Arduino sketch upload.

Also see  https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/nordic-blog/b/blog/posts/working-with-the-nrf52-series-improved-approtect